# Vue+Webpack app deploy on heroku not working when page is refreshed

Tags: heroku, vuejs2, vue-router

I generated a vue app using `vue-cli` with webpack template and deployed it to heroku using [this guide](https://medium.com/@sagarjauhari/quick-n-clean-way-to-deploy-vue-webpack-apps-on-heroku-b522d3904bc8). I was able to run it without problem but when I refresh the page, or I accessed a sub route directly it fails.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
app = express()
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname))
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(port)
console.log('server started '+ port)
```

**router.js**

My vue router config

`export default new Router({ mode: 'history', routes })`

Comment: Can you post the console log, if there's any errors on it? The development menu can be activated by `ctrl + shift + j` on Chrome.

Comment: @Mikael this is not a code based problem so there will no error on the console.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spa's generally have on one `index.html` and the navigation to other routes in the app is handled by javascript itself. This is causing failure when you refresh or directly access a sub-route.

Since you have `history` mode configured in your vuejs router configuration using `mode: 'history'` you can consider using [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) as described [here: Example server configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html).

1. `npm install --save connect-history-api-fallback`
2. Add this middleware to your express

   ```
   var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

   var express = require('express')
   var path = require('path')
   var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
   app = express()
   //add this middleware
   app.use(history());    
   app.use(serveStatic(__dirname))
   var port = process.env.PORT || 5000
   app.listen(port)
   console.log('server started '+ port)
   ```

Comment: Awesome solution!!

Comment: Is there a way to fix this issue without making any changes in the backend code (that is in node.js in my case)?